# How to know if my burned Windows7 DVD can still be used file?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, iso-image, dvd-burning

I've a burned Windows7 DVD from 2 years or maybe 3 I bought it from "Publinet" (Internet Café but without coffee!), what I want to know is, after all that time, how can I know if this DVD is missing any files and if its still usable or not?

I've also many other DVDs and I want to know if I can still use them without problems or not?

BTW, I'm using Ubuntu (if anyone will give a software link)

Comment: Why do you have reason to think that it may not be usable?  Unless it looks like it's in bad condition and/or it has been mistreated, a DVD burned 2-3 years ago should still be fine, assuming it was fine at the time.

Comment: @MosheKatz Because, I remember I had a problem when Installing it, in the end of Installation of Windows7 Ultimate. sometimes I get a problem and sometimes no, and, this time, I don't want to lose any files

Comment: You could always just burn a completely new copy.  [This page](http://www.w7forums.com/threads/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-image-downloads.12325/page-2#post-124821) has links to all of the official ISO images. (*Yes, those images are provided by Microsoft and hosted by a Microsoft-authorized site.*) It's probably easier to do that than to re-verify an old disc.  The images linked here may also be newer than the one you originally used so they may have updates pre-installed.

Comment: @MosheKatz I downloaded one but I had a problem when burning it, and I don't know it will work with this problem or not (it's burned, but the software stopped after that.. it's a bug in the software)